# Token based authentication and refresh mechanism : ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, authentication, access-token

Token based authentication is one of the security authentication method we follow.

But In case of authentication setting up the header with auth token do the job.But How to manage the webservices with refresh mechanism?As the token **expire** we have to deal with a web service and **create a new one**.So in a bigger app with lots of webservice interaction how can we manage?

Should we have to work on the failure mechanism in every webservice checking if the token fails, get new token and then call the option again?

In framework like AFNetworking or ASIHttp is this handled or we have to deal with code ourselves.If so how can or how should we deal with it?

> Get Token ->  Store in header -> Call Webservices -> Success
>
> Call weservice -> auth expire failure -> get new Token -> call Webservice again -> Success : How to handle this?

Comment: .I have also same situation, If you get any solution please add the answer.

Comment: Hey @Lithu, did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the token got from WS to NSUserDefaults with token as key. Therefore whenever you get new token, you just need to update the UserDefaults and get updated token from UserDefaults for next WS.

Comment: The  question is not about how or where to save token .It is about how to manage a failure case in the token expired error

Comment: Okay. What will be your response from server in case of token expired error?